# Trello Card without createCard action

Tags: trello

When using

```
https://api.trello.com/1/cards/{id}/actions?
```

I am finding some cards that do not have a corresponding action of type **createCard**.  I am getting cards with only **updateCard** actions.

Additionally, if the card has been archived, the list of actions returned does not include an action archiving the card.

Is that the expected behavior?  How can it be that there are cards without a createCard action? How to get the creation date for those cards?

Comment: I think, but I am not sure, that the issue is due to the fact that this specific card was created in a board I do not have permission.

Answer (score 0):

you should get the createCard action from the following endpoint

`/1/boards/${boardId}/actions?fields=idMemberCreator,date&idModels=${cardId}&filter=createCard`

Comment: i yet don't know about the archived cards

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue - I was using `/1/cards/{cardId}/actions?filter=createCard` (which got me the same results as Moazzam Arif's answer), where 53% of my 370 cards are missing the `createCard` date.

It turns out `createCard` is only added when creating a brand new card and a lot of my cards were converted from checklists, which is a different action. The available 'action types' that I've found (in Python format) are:

```
['convertToCardFromCheckItem',
'addChecklistToCard',
'createCard',
'updateCard',
'updateCheckItemStateOnCard',
'removeChecklistFromCard',
'commentCard']
```

(I found these through `/1/cards/{cardId}/actions?filter=all`).

Once I changed my URL to `/1/cards/{cardId}/actions?filter=createCard,convertToCardFromCheckItem`, I retrieved dates on all cards. Unfortunately Trello API doesn't support checklist creation date, so tracking only begins once the card is created.

I don't have any archived cards to test it, but it looks like the `closed` card object field is what you're looking for (https://developers.trello.com/reference#card-object).